# Curl a webpage passing login info in specific field

Tags: forms, curl

So, I have a webpage, which is a login form. What I want to do is curl the page, pass in the username and password and click on the submit form. Essentially, if the username and password are correct, it should return 200. The only thing is the username and password needs to be passed to two textboxes i.e. textbook1 and textbox2. Is this possible using curl or through any other command ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful walkthrough - https://journalxtra.com/linux/howto-pass-data-variables-to-curl-to-autofill-web-forms/

But if you're light on reading this may be what you're looking for

```
curl -d textbox1=username&textbox2=password url
```